# Assigning a height of 100vh to my main container in order to have all the content on the page without scrolling

Tags: html, css

I want to have all the container of my section on the screen without having the user to scroll down with the mouse in order to see everything that has been laid out. I have assigned a height of `100vh` to my main container but nevertheless it keeps scrolling.

Any help? Below's the code and and the code pen.

HTML

```
<div class="main_container">
<h3>404 not found</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper__item img">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1540786121371-70e1e61ac897?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"
                alt="scarecrow">
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper__item text">
            <h2>I have bad news <br> for you</h2>
            <p class="text">
                The page you are <br>looking
                for might be removed or <br> is
                temporarily unavailable
            </p>
            <a href="#" id="btn">Back to Homepage</a>
        </div>
        
    </div>
   <div class="markup">Created By</div>
</div>

CSS 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;900&family=Space+Mono:wght@400;700&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


body {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata',
        monospace;
    font-family: 'Space Mono',
        monospace;
}


.main_container {
    height: 100vh;
}

h3 {
    margin: 2rem 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata',
        monospace;
}



.img img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    margin-right: 1.6rem;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}

.wrapper h2 {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-size: 2.6rem;
}

.wrapper p {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}


#btn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #000;
    color: #ffff;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.markup{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Helye23/pen/vYGYovj

Answer (score 1):

Your `.wrapper` has `height: 100%` but your `h3`is above that so the content height of your `.main-container` will always be `100% + h3 height` that leads to overflowing everytime.

If the page still overflows than your content is too big for the users screen, and this can always happen. You can never trust that each user has a big screen. An alternative for that would be realtive sizes for your `img` and the text that lead to decreasing the size of the elements with a smaller screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `position: relative` on your `main_container` to make web page height to fit screen height. You also do not need height in the `.wrapper`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@400;900&family=Space+Mono:wght@400;700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main_container {
  position: relative;
}

body {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
}

h3 {
  margin: 2rem 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
}

.img img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10rem;
  margin-right: 1.6rem;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-size: 2.6rem;
}

.wrapper p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

#btn {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #ffff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.markup {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <h3>404 not found</h3>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper__item img">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1540786121371-70e1e61ac897?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80" alt="scarecrow">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__item text">
      <h2>I have bad news <br> for you</h2>
      <p class="text">
        The page you are <br>looking for might be removed or <br> is temporarily unavailable
      </p>
      <a href="#" id="btn">Back to Homepage</a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="markup">Created By</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately if I had the overflow property to the main container as you suggested the last div which contains the signature of the designer (me :)) will disappear

Answer (score 0):

it's overflow problem.
add `.main-container{ overflow:hidden; }`

Comment: Unfortunately if I had the overflow property to the main container as you suggested the last div which contains the signature of the designer (me :)) will disappear